# Elasticsearch Distinct query after setting fielddata to true

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get distinct values of a field "vip_name" on an index. 
This is what I tried to begin with:

```
curl -XGET http://172.31.38.157:9200/cb_inventory/_search -d 
'{"size":0,"aggs":{"vips":{"terms":{"field":"vip_name"}}}}'

{"error":{"root_cause":
[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled 
on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [vip_name] in order to 
load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that 
this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword 
field 
instead."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all 
shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":  [{"shard":0,
"index":"cb_inventory","node":"7_t7zG82QsS__Q_vRHWy9A","reason":
{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields
 by default.
```

OK. So I set fielddata to true as below:

```
curl -XPUT http://172.31.38.157:9200/cb_inventory/_mapping/cb_inventory -d '{"properties":{"vip_name":{"type":"text","fielddata":true}}}'
{"acknowledged":true}
```

Now I do the search and get back the below:

```
curl -XGET http://172.31.38.157:9200/cb_inventory/_search?pretty=true -d '{"size":0,"aggs":{"vips":{"terms":{"field":"vip_name","size":1000}}}}'
{"took" : 5,
 "timed_out" : false,
 "_shards" : {
   "total" : 5,
   "successful" : 5,
   "skipped" : 0,
   "failed" : 0
 },
"hits" : {
  "total" : 3,
   "max_score" : 0.0,
   "hits" : [ ]
 },
"aggregations" : {
  "vips" : {
   "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "domain.com",
      "doc_count" : 3
    },
    {
      "key" : "ppcbcl00021",
      "doc_count" : 3
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

This is a bit funny, since I have only one distinct value ppcbcl00021.domain.com . Now it is showing up as 2 broken distinct values.

How Do I go about getting a distinct value as "ppcbcl00021.domain.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `vip_name` is set into `text` not `keyword`. So, even though you have `ppcbcl00021.domain.com`, in the ES, it will be stored as chunk of text ie `ppcbcl00021` and `domain.com`.

Try again by setting `vip_name` to `keyword`

```
curl -XPUT http://172.31.38.157:9200/cb_inventory/_mapping/cb_inventory -d '{"properties":{"vip_name":{"type":"keyword"}}}'
```